# vc++ MFC Project

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-6

In Vc++ 6.0 mscomm control,please any body explain this function How it works ,what it does

```
if (m_comm.GetCommEvent()==2 ) 
        {   
            VARIANT in_dat;
            in_dat = m_comm.GetInput();
            CString strInput(in_dat.bstrVal);
            m_input = m_input + strInput;
            UpdateData(FALSE);  
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code checks whether a comm event occured. If it did, then the input data is obtained from the control and appended to m_input. Afterwards, the data is updated.

The code does not offer much more insight.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you don't know, "the data is updated" in HS' post means 'the dialog box fields are updated to show the new data'